# java spring mvc custom tag input text value as a ModelAttribute parameter of a form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using java and spring mvc and I am new in it.
I have just created custom tag that contains input text. Now I want to use this custom tag inside a form. This form should be passed to the controller as a ModelAttribute parameter. The custom tag doesn't have "form:" prefix in the input text and I don't have any path to  supply in the custom tag code. I can supply path value only in the form.
What is the best way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You could get it using the @RequestParam annotation in your controller method. As long as you know the name of the HTML element that is created by your custom tag, you can use that for the @RequestParam parameter:

```
public String myControllerMethod(@RequestParam String myElement) {
  ...
}
```

EDIT:

Or `@ModelAttribute` should work. Just make sure your `@ModelAttribute` class has a field (getter/setter) that matches the name of the HTML element.

```
public class MyBackingBean {
  private String myElementName;
  public String getMyElementName() {return myElementName;}
  public void setMyElementName(String myElementName) {this.myElementName = myElementName; }
...
}

public String myControllerMethod(@ModelAttribute MyBackingBean myBean) {
  System.out.println(myBean.getMyElementName());
  ...
}
```

Comment: So what is the difference between '@RequestParam' and '@ModelAttribute' ?

Comment: RequestParam maps exactly one request parameter to the method parameter. ModelAttribute can fill a whole bean object my mapping incoming request parameters to the getters/setters in the bean, matching by name. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Don't I need the 'form:' prefix??

Comment: No, as long as your custom tag outputs an HTML element with the proper name attribute. Spring's form:input just ends up as regular HTML on the client side.